# How to group by on two fields and count

Tags: mysql

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `usuarios` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `user1` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `user2` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 AUTO_INCREMENT=1 ;

INSERT INTO `usuarios` (`id`, `user1`, `user2`) VALUES
(1, 'pepe', NULL),
(2, 'pepe', 'juan'),
(3, 'juan', NULL),
(4, 'juan', NULL),
(5, 'juan', 'pepe'),
(6, NULL, 'pepe'),
(7, 'pepe', 'juan');
```

I need to make a query: I have done this:

```
SELECT
`user1`,
COUNT(`id`) AS Total
FROM usuarios
WHERE (`user1` is not null)
GROUP BY `user1`
UNION
SELECT
`user2`,
COUNT(`id`) AS Total
FROM usuarios
WHERE (`user2` is not null)
GROUP BY `user2`
```

But the result is:

```
user1    total
juan      3
pepe      3
juan      2
pepe      2
```

I need to remove duplicate names, add up the total and this is the result:

```
user1    total
juan      5
pepe      5
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT users, COUNT(*) FROM (
    SELECT
    `user1` AS users
    FROM usuarios
    WHERE (`user1` is not null)
    UNION ALL
    SELECT
    `user2`
    FROM usuarios
    WHERE (`user2` is not null)
) sq 
GROUP BY users;
```

Do the grouping outside. The trick is to use `UNION ALL` instead of `UNION`. The latter one uses a `distinct` on the result. You don't have to include the `id` column in the subqueries, so you can later count it, because it's the primary key and doesn't allow `null` values anyway.